# Django models order by database - best practice

Tags: django, django-models, sql-order-by

When creating a model in Django, what is the best practice to also store dynamically the order of its objects?

A simple way would be to add a IntegerField and let the content managers to set it as they wish, and to order the objects by it.

Best way would cause in the admin interface the option to manipulate the objects. like in this simple [jquery ui sortable demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/)

It is very common case (for me, and for many others) , so it is important to not manipulate the database very much,yet do it as generic as possible.

Comment: In fact, there is no need of database manipulation. If you are using `ModelForm`, you can specify it in `Meta.fields` option, and order of fields in a `Form` class is always applied in the template. Using a such Js is enough for user-interface ordering.

Comment: @FallenAngel I need the ability to give the site editors the options to decide how things will be ordered, and they don't know python..and it should be dynamic, rather than hard-coded